# Cypress - Why adding testfiles names in jsconfig.json file are not executing in order

Tags: testing, cypress, execution

I have added spec file names in jsconfig.json so that they can execute in order. But they are not executing in this order.

[image]

```js
{
  "include": ["./node_modules/cypress", "cypress/**/*.js"],
  "testFiles":
  [
    "login.cy.js",
    "create_course.cy.js",
    "open_course.cy.js",
    "create_training.cy.js",
    "edit_pitch.cy.js"
  ]

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `specPattern`, you can add a String or Array of glob patterns of the test files to load. Unfortunately, you won't be able to add the spec files in an array-like you can do in cypress version < 10 with `testFiles`.

An alternate way would be to keep the spec pattern as `["cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"]` and then rename your spec files to include sequential numbers so that they are executed in that sequence.

```js
01-login.cy.js
02-create_course.cy.js
03-open_course.cy.js
04-create_training.cy.js
05-edit_pitch.cy.js
```

Comment: I tried your solution. but it says No Specs Found for these files. Although exact specs files exist in e2e folder.

Comment: Ok, you have to also add the folder name in front as the specPattern directly searches for files in the e2e root. Updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry to say but for me it is still not working by adding folder name in front. :/

Comment: Please add your `cypress.config.js` file.

Comment: I have added screenshot above. please check.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to execute specs in order is to import them into a parent spec.

This also means you can run them together in the Cypress test runner (a feature removed in Cypress v10)

**all-spec.cy.js**

```js
// run this spec to run the following in sequence

import './login.cy.js'
import './create_course.cy.js'
import './open_course.cy.js'
import './create_training.cy.js'
import './edit_pitch.cy.js'
```